# Not receiving traffic in suricata on proxmox host machine from other hosts

Tags: linux, proxmox, ids, suricata

I am running proxmox on my server machine. I have attached a bridge adapter to it and 2 containers (A and B) are installed on proxmox.

I have also install Suricata on the Proxmox machine for it to act as an IDS. I have setup promiscuous mode on my bridge adapter in order to receive traffic from other machines present in my local network. However, in the Suricata logs, i am only receiving logs relating to my Containers (A and B) and not from the other Devices (Non Proxmox Based) present in my local network.

Answer (score 0):

suricata installed directly on proxmox server is not good at all, you must do any if this

1. redirect (mirror) all traffic from home router to suricata (proxmox), it can be setup on router or switch before router - based on what you have there, but sending all traffic to proxmox(suricata) is bad idea, you will see
2. buy some rpi4 (4 or 8GB ram) make pfsense running on it with suricata "addon" or suricata itself - place it in front of your main LAN gateway/router and reconfigure all home devices to use it as gateway